# TryOpenExisting() и использование Discards (пустых переменных) на обьектах которые наследуют IDisposable

Tags: c#, c#-faq, mutex, c#-7.0

Мне нужно только результат функции, который записывается в переменную existing.

```
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: out Mutex _);
```

Могу ли я использовать "Пустую переменную" в этом коде? Вызовет ли она Dispose(); для этого обьекта автоматически?

Или правильным было бы обьявить переменную `Mutex mutex` и после вызова метода вызвать `mutex.Dispose();` ?

P.S. Кому не понятна суть вопроса, подробнее про пустые переменные тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards

Comment: Что такое отбрасывание?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards

Comment: а в русском варианте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/discards где конкретно есть слово отбрасывание? Я честно все еще не понимаю отбрасывание имеется ввиду :) Даже с этим линком

Comment: Исправил на "Пустую переменную"

Comment: Пустая переменная, это проще говоря вот этот знак "_"

Comment: @Andrew В данном примере (в вопросе) программист хочет подчеркнуть, что его интересует булевский результат вызова, а не значение `out` параметра.

Comment: Ребят, я хотел узнать нужно ли вызывать Dispose() для полученного Mutex или достаточно этот Mutex отбросить с помощью пустой переменной, и все ресурсы будут высвобождены корректно?

Comment: Считаю что нужно вернуть вопрос к первоначальному виду, т.к. теперь вопрос "спрашивает" совсем не то что меня интересует...

Comment: так вопрос сейчас именно это и спрашивает, то что ты написал в передпоследнем коментарии.

Comment: Да, вопрос интересный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сама документация описывает что "пустые переменные" просто ссылаются на некую "пустую" область памяти. То есть не занимают места.

Что вряд ли означает что они будут вызывать Dispose() у IDisposable обьектов.

---

Я провел личное расследование даного вопроса и написал прогу для тестирования. Простая винформс апликуха на старте которого вызывается метод:

```
public bool TestMethod(out Image bmp)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\UKS\Desktop\2000x2000pixels.bmp");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    return true;
}
```

Выкладываю результаты:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Image img;
    var a = TestMethod(out img);
    img.Dispose();
}
```

[image: Память возросла и освободилась т.к. мы использовали диспоуз]

Как видно из картинки - Память возросла и освободилась т.к. мы использовали диспоуз

Теперь настал черед теста:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var a = TestMethod(out _);
}
```

[image: Как видим из картинки - память НЕ освободилась когда я использовал Discard переменную]

Как видим из картинки - память НЕ освободилась когда я использовал Discard-переменную.

Из чего делаем вывод что Дискарды не диспоузят данные. Теперь настал черед еще пары тестов:

Конструкция:

```
var a = TestMethod(out _.Dispose());
```

Не сработает. Говорит что _ не существует в даном контексте.

Конструкция:

```
var a = TestMethod(out _);
_.Dispose();
```

Даст ровно тот же результат.

**Вывод: пустые переменные использовать на IDisposable обьектах категорически нельзя.**

---

---

**Итак, самый коректный код в даном конкретном случае есть:**

```
Mutex mutex; 
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: mutex);
mutex?.Dispose();//проверяем на null. Если не налл, то вызываем диспоуз.
```

Comment: Эм-м... Но в случае с мьютексом может вернуться null. Тогда вызов Dispose приведёт к исключению. Отсюда вопрос: в этом случае (null) мьютекс вообще создается или нет? Очевидно, нет. И память не тратится, и ресурсы не занимаются, и Dispose не нужен. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: а в чем конкретно проблема проверить на null перед вызовом Dispose в случае с мьютексом?

Comment: Кажется, разобрался, как оно устроено.

Comment: Спасибо за исследование, результат немного огорчает конечно, но что поделать, буду явно высвобождать получаемыеMutex